# AudioController class for managing audio in Unity games

Tags: c#, unity3d, audio

I'm looking for a critique of this audio management system I wrote for Unity games. It references a JSON file to trigger the clips by events.

The main AudioController.cs class is pasted below. The full codebase can be found here: https://github.com/GlowLimeGames/audio-system-unity

```
/*
* Authors): Isaiah Mann 
* Description: Used to control the audio in the game
* Is a Singleton (only one instance can exist at once)
* Attached to a GameObject that stores all AudioSources and AudioListeners for the game
* Dependencies: AudioFile, AudioLoader, AudioList, AudioUtil, RandomizedQueue<AudioFile>
*/
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AudioController : MonoBehaviour {

public bool isAudioListener = true;

// Singleton implementation
public static AudioController Instance;

const string path = "Audio/AudioList";
AudioList fileList;
AudioLoader loader;


// Stores all the audio sources and files inside dictionaries
Dictionary<int, AudioSource> channels = new Dictionary<int, AudioSource>();
Dictionary<string, AudioFile> files = new Dictionary<string, AudioFile>();

// Stores all the audio events inside dictionaries
Dictionary<string, List<AudioFile>> playEvents = new Dictionary<string, List<AudioFile>>();
Dictionary<string, List<AudioFile>> stopEvents = new Dictionary<string, List<AudioFile>>();

// Audio Control Patterns
RandomizedQueue<AudioFile> _swells;
RandomizedQueue<AudioFile> _sweeteners;
IEnumerator _swellCoroutine;
IEnumerator _sweetenerCoroutine;

// Set to false to halt active coroutines
bool _coroutinesActive = true;
[Header("Sweeteners")]
public float ShortestSweetenerPlayFrequenecy = 10;
public float LongestSweetenerPlayFrequenecy = 25;

void Awake () {
    Init();
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void OnDestroy () {
    // Garbage collection: otherwise events will produce null reference errors when called
    UnsubscribeEvents();
}

public void Play (AudioFile file) {

    AudioSource source = GetChannel(file.Channel);

    CheckMute(file, source);

    source.clip = file.Clip;

    source.loop = file.Loop;

    source.volume = file.Volumef;

    source.Play();

}

public void Stop (AudioFile file) {

    if (ChannelExists(file.Channel)) {
        AudioSource source = GetChannel(file.Channel);

        if (source.clip == file.Clip) {

            source.Stop();

        }
    }

}

public void ToggleFXMute () {
    SettingsUtil.ToggleFXMuted (
        !SettingsUtil.FXMuted
    );
}

public void ToggleMusicMute () {
    SettingsUtil.ToggleMusicMuted (
        !SettingsUtil.MusicMuted
    );
}

void CheckMute (AudioFile file, AudioSource source) {
    source.mute = AudioUtil.IsMuted(file.typeAsEnum);
}

// Checks if the AudioSource corresponding to the channel integer has been initialized
bool ChannelExists (int channelNumber) {
    return channels.ContainsKey(channelNumber);
}

AudioSource GetChannel (int channelNumber) {
    if (channels.ContainsKey(channelNumber)) {

        return channels[channelNumber];

    } else {

        // Adds a new audiosource if channel is not present in dictionary
        AudioSource newSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        channels.Add(channelNumber, newSource);
        return newSource;

    }
}


// Must be colled to setup the class's functionality
void Init () {

    // Singleton method returns a bool depending on whether this object is the instance of the class
    if (SingletonUtil.TryInit(ref Instance, this, gameObject)) {

        loader = new AudioLoader(path);
        fileList = loader.Load();

        InitFileDictionary(fileList);

        AddAudioEvents();

        SubscribeEvents();

        if (isAudioListener) {
            AddAudioListener();
        }

        // TODO: Enable after tracks have been delivered
        // initCyclingAudio();

    }
}

void InitFileDictionary (AudioList audioFiles) {
    for (int i = 0; i < audioFiles.Length; i++) {
        files.Add (
            audioFiles[i].FileName,
            audioFiles[i]
        );
    }
}

void AddAudioEvents () {

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Length; i++) {

        AddPlayEvents(fileList[i]);
        AddStopEvents(fileList[i]);

    }

}

void AddPlayEvents (AudioFile file) {

    for (int j = 0; j < file.EventNames.Length; j++) {

        if (playEvents.ContainsKey(file.EventNames[j])) {

            playEvents[file.EventNames[j]].Add(file);

        } else {

            List<AudioFile> files = new List<AudioFile>();
            files.Add(file);

            playEvents.Add (
                file.EventNames[j],
                files
            );

        }

    }

}

void AddStopEvents (AudioFile file) {

    for (int j = 0; j < file.StopEventNames.Length; j++) {

        if (stopEvents.ContainsKey(file.StopEventNames[j])) {

            stopEvents[file.StopEventNames[j]].Add(file);

        } else {

            List<AudioFile> files = new List<AudioFile>();
            files.Add(file);

            stopEvents.Add (
                file.StopEventNames[j],
                files
            );

        }

    }

}

// Uses C#'s delegate system
void SubscribeEvents () {
    EventController.OnNamedEvent += HandleEvent;
    EventController.OnAudioEvent += HandleEvent;
}

void UnsubscribeEvents () {
    EventController.OnNamedEvent -= HandleEvent;
    EventController.OnAudioEvent -= HandleEvent;
}

void HandleEvent (string eventName) {

    if (playEvents.ContainsKey(eventName)) {

        PlayAudioList(
            playEvents[eventName]
        );
    }

    if (stopEvents.ContainsKey(eventName)) {

        StopAudioList(
            stopEvents[eventName]
        );
    }

}

void HandleEvent (AudioActionType actionType, AudioType audioType) {

    if (AudioUtil.IsMuteAction(actionType)) {

        HandleMuteAction (actionType, audioType);

    }

}

void HandleMuteAction (AudioActionType actionType, AudioType audioType) {
    foreach (AudioSource source in channels.Values) {

        if (fileList.GetAudioType(source.clip) == audioType) {

            source.mute = AudioUtil.MutedBoolFromAudioAction(actionType);

        }

    }
}

void PlayAudioList (List<AudioFile> files) {
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++) {
        Play(files[i]);
    }
}

void StopAudioList (List<AudioFile> files) {
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++) {
        Stop(files[i]);
    }
}

void AddAudioListener () {
    gameObject.AddComponent<AudioListener>();
}

// Used to loop through lists of tracks in pseudo-random order
void startTrackCycling () {
    _sweetenerCoroutine = cycleTracksFrequenecyRange(
        _sweeteners,
        ShortestSweetenerPlayFrequenecy,
        LongestSweetenerPlayFrequenecy
    );

    _swellCoroutine = cycleTracksContinuous (
        _swells
    );

    startCoroutines(
        _sweetenerCoroutine,
        _swellCoroutine
    );
}

void initCyclingAudio () {
    //TODO: Init Queue's with sound files once they're delivered
    _sweeteners = new RandomizedQueue<AudioFile>();
    _swells = new RandomizedQueue<AudioFile>();
    startTrackCycling();
}

// Plays audio files back to back
IEnumerator cycleTracksContinuous (RandomizedQueue<AudioFile> files) {
    while (_coroutinesActive) { 
        AudioFile nextTrack = files.Cycle();
        Play(nextTrack);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(nextTrack.Clip.length);
    }
}

// Plays audio files on a set frequenecy
IEnumerator cycleTracksFrequenecy (RandomizedQueue<AudioFile> files, float frequenecy) {
    while (_coroutinesActive) {
        Play(files.Cycle());
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(frequenecy);
    }
}

// Coroutine that varies the frequency with which it plays audio files
IEnumerator cycleTracksFrequenecyRange (RandomizedQueue<AudioFile> files, float minFrequency, float maxFrequency) {
    while (_coroutinesActive) {
        Play(files.Cycle());

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(
            UnityEngine.Random.Range(
                minFrequency, 
                maxFrequency
            )
        );
    }
}


// Starts an arbitrary amount of coroutines
void startCoroutines (params IEnumerator[] coroutines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < coroutines.Length; i++) {
        StartCoroutine(coroutines[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Targeting only the use of `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>`.

Using `ContainsKey()` together with the getter of the `Item` property of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` should be replaced by a call to `TryGetValue()` which is faster because the check if the key exists is done by the Item getter as well.

Internally these three methods are calling the [`FindEntry()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1) method to check whether a given key exists.

So calling this method only once through the `TryGetValue()` method should be the way to go like so:

```
AudioSource GetChannel(int channelNumber) {

    AudioSource source = null;
    if (channels.TryGetValue(channelNumber, out source))
    {
        return source;
    }

    source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    channels.Add(channelNumber, source );

    return source ;
}
```